# How to add external javascript on popup?

Tags: javascript

I have a splashify popup with links on the front page I want to set a cookie when the link is clicked but the external javascript I have written to set cookie is not working on popup.

How to add external javascript on popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722) there are various methods to add your own js. I assume you are using Drupal 7, this is important because in Drupal 8 adding js is different.

Also your js code needs to be like this

```
(function ($) {
  $( document ).ready(function() {
            // custom code goes here
  });
}(jQuery));
```